# Handling special characters in and out of mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm building a leaflet web app which stores messages assigned to geolocations.

I add data one line at a time by sending it from javascript to PHP using:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['NAME']);
$latitude = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['LATITUDE']);
$longitude = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['LONGITUDE']);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['MESSAGE']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO geoData (NAME,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,MESSAGE)
VALUES ('$name', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$message')";
```

I get the data back out using PHP to echo the data back to javascript using:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername,$dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
if(! $conn ){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM geoData';

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
 } else {
    echo "0 results";
 } 

mysqli_close($conn);

<script type="text/javascript">
        var data = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($rows); ?> ' ); 
</script>
```

This works fine UNLESS the message has special characters such as apostrophes for example 'Dave's dogs's bone'. This creates an error

What is the best practise for such an application which uses PHP and javascript. I think I need some way to encode the special characters which javascript can then decode and display.

The error comes as:
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var data = JSON.parse( '[{"NAME":"The Kennel","LATITUDE":"50.7599143982","LONGITUDE":"-1.3100980520","MESSAGE","Dave's Dog's Bone"}] ' ); 
</script>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Side note: `mysqli_error()` isn't the correct function to test if a connection failed or not. You need `mysqli_connect_error()`.

Comment: *"This creates an error"* - Being what exactly? You didn't say.

Comment: Use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually escaping and building your queries like that. When you're using prepared statements, you don't need to escape anything since everything is handled by the server.

Comment: Please add example output (as opposed to PHP source code) to your question and post the exact error you're getting, verbatim.

Comment: You need to set the database tables, your php file and your html to the correct encoding - say 'UTF-8' - https://phptherightway.com/#php_and_utf8_title

Comment: Sounds like it's suppertime over your way; same here, gotta run just as you may have done. Good luck.

Comment: I assume the apostrophe is not being escaped... The string should be "Dave\'s dogs\'s bone". Check if that is what's coming out of your json_encode

Comment: Who are people above which suggest PDO? Who are which upvote you all? OP asks you how to escape JSON, not a SQL query.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner it was a "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" because of the extra quote mark. I'm looking for the correct way to do this as I am learning rather than how to just fix my code. I'll look up prepared statements.

Comment: @user1597430 - You're the only one that mentioned PDO. I mentioned Prepared Statements since the title asks about handling special chars both in and out. Using prepared statements are best practice for in data (and the best way to protect your code from SQL injections), which is why it's mentioned. Also,  the OP hadn't actually told us what the error was or where it occurred when that comment was posted. Please read the time line/edits in the question and when the comments were posted.

Comment: You can try adding [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) should the data contain '\ in the db values.

Comment: Rule of thumb: DO NOT USE `JSON.parse()` or `JSON.stringify` unless you understand what they do.

Comment: For @Funk Forty Niner and others: OP does not have any issue with DB data. Also, `stripslashes` is usually a dirty workaround from people who don't know about default mysqli functions for string escaping. His issue is in the JSON escaping/understanding.

Comment: @user1597430 Yeah I know. I don't work with JSON, so I wasn't able to provide them with an (quick) answer. If I'd be in their situtation, I'd use my searching skills; *that* I'm prrrretty good at ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - From what I've seen, you're pretty darn good at most things :-p

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks Magnus. I'll Google till the cows come home if need be ;-) For days even. If I can't get something to work, I'll ask a few friends, but I usually end up on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is your `JSON.parse()` which isn't needed at all in this case.

Change:

```
var data = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($rows); ?> ' );
```

to

```
var data = <?= json_encode($rows); ?>;
```

`JSON.parse()` is for parsing stringified json. Echoing the result from `json_encode()` will give you the correct result straight away.

**Side note**

I would recommend adding `$rows = [];` before your `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)` or `json_encode($rows)` will throw an "undefined variable" if the query doesn't return any results (since that variable currently is created inside the loop when you're looping through the results).

**Side note 2**

When making database queries, it's recommended to use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for manually escaping and building your queries. Prepared statements are currently the recommended way to protect yourself against SQL injections and makes sure you don't forget or miss to escape some value.

Comment: This works, is it secure? There are some comments above talking about prepared statements. I thought I had done this, using            $sql = "INSERT INTO geoData (NAME,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,MESSAGE)
VALUES ('$name', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$message')";           what should I be doing?

Comment: Prepared statements are for your database queries. This answer is about how to output the result as json (fixing your current error). Two totally different things. Also, the above query uses string interpolation (which is not prepared statements). Read the link I posted in the comment about prepared statements under your question.

Comment: Will do, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You produce that error yourself by adding ' in json. If you want check that use this:

```
JSON.parse( '[{"NAME":"The Kennel","LATITUDE":"50.7599143982","LONGDITUTE":"-1.3100980520","type":"bad","reason":"Dave\'s Dog\'s Bone","improvement":"","reviewed":"0"}] ' );
```

And if you want correct that in main code use `str.replace(/'/g, '"')` for your var data, before parse it to json.